# Is it true that $f(z)=u(z,0)+iv(z,0)$ for complex $z$ and why?

Tags: complex-analysis

As in the title, i came across this equivalence
$$f(z)=f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)=u(z,0)+iv(z,0)$$ while reading my notes on complex analysis, and tried to see why is it true, but i couldn't figure it out. Maybe it could be true only in the case that f is holomorphic.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense: $u$ and $v$ are functions of real variables ($x$ and $y$), right? What does $u(z, 0)$ mean when $z$ is complex?

Comment: All identities except the last one are correct: if $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$, then each point on it's image has a unique real part and imaginary part. Thus, it defines two unique functions from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. As each point on the domain has a unique expression as $z = x + iy$, $u(x, y)$ and $v(x, y)$ are thus defined. The converse is also true: if I have both $u$ and $v$, I can define a unique function $f(z) = f(x + iy) = u(x, y) + iv(x, y)$. I cannot make sense of the last equality.

Comment: Yes, the last one had me confused. In the notes it stated that this is true "by a known rule".

Comment: Ask the author of the notes what they mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by many, as written this doesn't make much sense (unless $z$ is real, in which case it's trivial). However, I think what is trying to be communicated is a certain calculational trick.

Let's start with the example $f(z) = e^z$. Then $u(x,y) = e^x \cos (y)$ and $v(x,y) = e^x \sin (y)$, so if we now redefine $u,v$ using these same formulae as functions of two *complex* variables, we see

$$ u(z,0) + i v(z,0) = e^z \cos(0) + i e^z \sin(0) = f(z).$$

In general, for any analytic function

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (a_n + i b_n) z^n,$$

with $a_n,b_n$ real, for **real** $z$ we have

$$ u(z,0) = \sum_n a_n z^n \; \text{ and } \; v(z,0) = \sum_n b_n z^n.$$

Reinterpreting these now as complex analytic functions (i.e. defining $\tilde u : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C : z \mapsto \sum_n a_n z^n$ and likewise $\tilde v$) we have $$f(z) = \tilde u (z) + i \tilde v(z).$$

Thus we get the trick: if you can write down $u(x,0)$ and $v(x,0)$ as some formulae in terms of elementary analytic functions, replacing $x$ with $z$ in $u(x,0) + i v(x,0)$ will give you the correct formula for $f(z)$ on the whole plane.

Comment: Now, this makes sense!

Comment: What if domain of $f$ does not contain origin , (then how we can expand power series at origin).

Answer (score 1):

If $z\mapsto f(z)=u(x,y)+i v(x,y)$ is analytic in a disc $D_\rho:=\bigl\{z\>\bigm|\>|z|<\rho\bigr\}$  then so is the function $$\check f(z):=\overline{f(\bar z)}\ .$$
It follows that the functions
$$U(z):={f(z)+\check f(z)\over2},\qquad V(z):={f(z)-\check f(z)\over 2i}$$ are analytic in $D_\rho$ as well, and $$f(z)=U(z)+i V(z)\ .$$

On the other hand, when $z=x\in D_\rho\cap{\mathbb R}\>$ one has
$$U(x)={f(x)+\overline {f(x)}\over 2}=u(x,0),\qquad V(x)={f(x)-\overline {f(x)}\over 2i}=v(x,0)\ .$$
This shows that the functions $x\mapsto u(x,0)$ and $x\mapsto v(x,0)$ each have a natural  extension from the $x$-axis to the complex $z$-plane, and these extensions are analytic functions of $z\in D_\rho$. In this way the "strange" functions $z\mapsto u(z,0)$ and $z\mapsto v(z,0)$ appearing in the question have an easy explanation: The $u(z,0)$ from the question is my $U(z)$, and similarly for $v(z,0)=V(z)$.

Comment: So for the equality to hold z must be real?

Answer (score 0):

For any function $f\colon \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, there exists two unique functions $u, v\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying:

$$f(z) = f(x + iy) = u(x, y) + iv(x, y)$$

They are defined simply by:

$$u(x, y) = \text{Re}(f(x + iy))$$
$$v(x, y) = \text{Im}(f(x + iy))$$

This is valid because each complex number $z$ has a unique expression of the form $x + iy$, with $x$ and $y$ real numbers. The last identity on your question is true if and only if $z$ lies on the real axis. Then, $z$ is a real number and thus it's value at $u(z, 0)$ and $v(z, 0)$ is well defined.

Answer (score -1):

It suffices to check when $f(z) = z^n$. Observe
\begin{align}
(x+iy)^n =& \sum^n_{k=1} \binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}(iy)^k = \sum_{k \text{ even}}\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}(iy)^k + \sum_{k\text{ odd}}\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}(iy)^k \\
=&\ \sum \binom{n}{2\ell}(-1)^\ell x^{n-2\ell}y^{2\ell} + i\sum \binom{n}{2\ell+1}(-1)^\ell x^{n-2\ell-1}y^{2\ell+1} \\ 
=&\ u(x, y) + iv(x, y)
\end{align} 
and observe 
\begin{align}
u(z, 0) + iv(z, 0) = z^n. 
\end{align}
Thus, when $f(z) = z^n$, we have $f(z) = u(z, 0) + iv(z, 0)$.

In the case when $f$ is not analytic the claim is false. For instance, 
\begin{align}
f(z) = \bar z  = x-iy  \ \ \text{ but } \ \ u(z, 0)+iv(z, 0) = z \neq \bar z. 
\end{align}

Comment: This reproduces the (deep) mistake already in the question. If $u:\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$, then $u(z,0)$ for $z$ in $\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R$ is not defined.

Answer (score -1):

You need to know what your functions $V,U$ are allowed to be.If   $U,V \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ then the only option $z$ is  $z \in  \mathbb{R}$   and your statement is true.You cant pick a different $z$ when your functions are not  defined accordingly.